# Background process terminates after a while in Google Cloud VM

Tags: ubuntu, google-cloud-platform, background-process, nohup

I am running my application in google cloud VM (e2 medium with Ubuntu 20.04) using the command

```
nohup node server.js > out.log &
```

I closed the ssh connection, it runs for a while, and then, the application terminates. I checked the log and there is no error. I didn't even requested anything from the server during this time. I also checked the instance metrics in google cloud console and the CPU utilization is always below 10%. I tested in my PC and this problem didn't happen.

[image]

Why is my application terminating in the cloud?

Comment: Nohup is not a reliable method to run a process in the background. This article discusses the various methods. https://www.dev2qa.com/how-to-run-node-js-server-in-background/ You should use a method similar to #4 in the article.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by @John Hanley Nohup is not a reliable method to run a process in the background. Although this is a common way to run processes in the background, it does not give you good control over the process. You cannot stop or restart the process easily. The problem with nohup is that if you don't send the output to > /dev/null 2>&1 then it will keep the output process open. So if you close the terminal, you also close the output process.

Instead of using nohop, you can use **systemd service** to run the background process.  Systemd is a more robust service when compared to nohop. Most Linux systems have systemd that allow you to define & manage services. You can easily start, stop or restart your script using systemctl command. Refer Method #3 in [How to Run NodeJS App in Background](https://fedingo.com/how-to-run-nodejs-app-in-background/) for information.

You can also use a **Screen** Command to Keep SSH Sessions Running, which allows you to reconnect to the process if it is interactive. Screen is a text Window Manager for Linux which allows users to manage multiple terminal sessions at same time, switching between sessions, session logging for the running sessions on screen, and even resuming the session at any time we desire without worrying about the session being logged out or terminal being closed.  It may be more cumbersome if you want many processes to run in background but if that's just one it's pretty easy.

**Install screen:** sudo apt install screen, run it with screen and treat it as another screen, run whatever you want and then just press **ctrl + a d** and you will be back to "original" shell. If you want to resume your screen sessions type screen -r. Refer [How to use Linux screen](https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-use-linux-screen/) for information.

Refer [How To Run Node JS Server In Background](https://www.dev2qa.com/how-to-run-node-js-server-in-background/)  and [How to keep processes running after ending ssh session](https://askubuntu.com/questions/8653/how-to-keep-processes-running-after-ending-ssh-session) for information.

Comment: Very good answer.